# Ionic api not works properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Can anyone tell why Api not working on real device? I am using .subscribe() or .pipe() to get or post api's
..
It works fine in browser, many people asking the same question on the internet but i dont find the best answer... Anyone? Knows the solution

Comment: posting some code will be helpfull and you get any errros in console

Comment: It may be due to CORS issue. Please check.

Comment: Actually i was facing the cors issues so i just asked to backend developer to enable CORS from server and then apis works fine, but now i am facing this problem, when i open it on real device its shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Api's were not working on real device because of the CORS issue, when backend developer enable the CORS now i am getting Api response in all devices.